# How to stack two columns in bootstrap on a large screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a grid layout for a website using bootstrap framework. I want a grid that displays 2 stacking divs that span the width of col-lg-4 next to one large div that spans the width of col-lg-8 and is equal in height to the two stacking div's.

```
<div class="mockups_wadels">
    <div class="div_center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 grid_padding">
                    <div class="wadels_dark">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 grid_padding">
                    <div class="wadels_embroidery">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid_padding">
                    <div class="wadels_white">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--end of row-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="wadels_browser">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--container end-->
    </div><!--end div center-->
</div><!--end of mockup-->
```

Here is a jsfiddle to help illustrate. My issue is that I do not know how to force the two col-lg-4 divs to stack on top of each other. Instead of stacking the second div simply starts a new row. http://jsfiddle.net/Dinkledine/0w2fppx6/

desire result

[image: desired result]

thanks for your help

Comment: I think I understand now what you meant. You want a 4 + 8 row ( with the 4 being stacked by another 4) and matching heights ? Edit : What is your `grid-padding` doing ?

Comment: yes that is correct. apologies if that was confusing. It was hard to put into words. the end result should form a large square with 3 parts.

Comment: Maximum in one row is 12 columns so you can use 2xcol-lg-2 + col-lg-8 or col-lg-2 + col-lg-8 + col-lg-2 i am not sure what layout you want

Comment: Also you can just write this col-sm-2+col-sm-2+col-sm-8 and it will break on sm width you dont have to write all those col- ...

Comment: Apologies for the confusion i've added a picture above to illustrate what result I am looking for :P

Comment: [This is the markup you're looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/hfr9zw4v/), but the real issue will be getting the two stacked DIVs to fill in the space equal to the DIV on the right. If you can use specific heights, that not a problem. Unfortunately I do not have a solution off the top of my head as to how to handle this dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution with panel and col layout.If you need padding remove nopadding from class

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
 .nopadding {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
 }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div class="container-fluid row-offcanvas nopadding">
   <div class="col-sm-5 nopadding">
    <!--Content 1-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 nopadding">  
     <div class="panel panel-default nopadding">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: lightblue; color: #000; font-weight:bold">content 1</div>
       <div class="panel-body" style="height:270px;overflow:auto;"></div>    
      <div class="panel-footer" style="background-color: lightblue;"></div>
     </div>
    </div><!--Content 1 Ends-->

    <!--Content 2-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 nopadding" >
     <div class="panel panel-default nopadding">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: lightsteelblue; font-weight:bold">content 2</div>
       <div  class="panel-body" style="height:270px;overflow:auto;"></div> 
      <div class="panel-footer" style="background-color: lightsteelblue;"></div>
     </div>
    </div><!--Content 2 Ends-->
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-7 nopadding">
    <!--Content 3 -->
    <div  class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 nopadding">   
     <div class="panel panel-default nopadding">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: lightsteelblue; font-weight:bold">Content 3</div>
       <div class="panel-body" style="height:602px;overflow:auto;"></div>
      <div class="panel-footer" style="background-color: lightsteelblue;"></div>
     </div>  
    </div><!--Content 3 Ends -->
   </div>
 </div> <!--row--> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Remember that rows are 12 column based so you think about the **bigger** layout.

You initially split your screen the way you want ( 4 + 8 ) , inside of those is where the magic happens !

Since a 12 col wide div is occupying the whole space ( it could be a container or any sized div ), the next div will stack below it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is best solution but check it out http://jsfiddle.net/b4voqjud/2/

```
<div class="mockups_wadels">
<div class="div_center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="wadels_dark"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="wadels_dark"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="wadels_dark"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="wadels_browser">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--container end-->
</div><!--end div center-->
</div><!--end of mockup-->
```

And if you want those two colums to always be same height i don't think you can do that with bootstrap and you have to use javascript, or flexbox, or just adjust padding on different device sizes